# Perl regex to match backslash at end of the string

Tags: regex, perl

```
$str = '\good\day';
$str =~ s#\\#\\\\#g;
print $str;
```

Result is : \\good\\day

When

```
my $str = '\good\day\';
```

I would like to get the result \\good\\day\\

Regex  `$str =~ s#\\#\\\\#g;` doesn't give the expected result.

Can you please help me?

Comment: So you want to have *2 **back** slashes* at the begin and end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shouldn't even compile.  It should give the error:

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF
```

You need to escape the second backslash in your single quoted string declaration.  Just like you have to escape a single quote with a backslash, you also need to escape backslashes at the end of a single quoted string.

This code will work as you intend:

```
my $str = '\good\day\\';

print "From: ", $str, "\n";

$str =~ s#\\#\\\\#g;

print "  To: ", $str, "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
From: \good\day\
  To: \\good\\day\\
```